# Trying to get a C++ switch statement to recognise spaces, tabs, etc

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that takes input and returns the input with all spaces, tabs, line breaks replaced with some arbitrary text.

As is my code compiles fine, but when the program is run, all spaces etc are ignored.  I.e. I input "Some text" and the output will be "Sometext".

My code is as follows:

```
// escapechars.cpp
#include <iostream>

std::string escapeChar(char ch)
{

    //Read in a character and return 
    //a string.
    std::string return_string("");

    switch(ch)
    {
        // space case
        case 32:
            return_string = "Space";
            return return_string;
        // tab case
        case 9:
            return_string = "TAB";
            return return_string;
        // carriage return case
        case 10:
            return_string = "CR";
            return return_string;
        // new line case
        case 13:
            return_string = "LF";
            return return_string;
        // backslash case
        case 92:
            return std::string(2, ch);
        case 48-57:
            return_string = "\\" + ch;
        default:
            return_string = ch;
            return return_string;
    }

}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Time to read in some characters or whatever...\n";
    char value;
    while (std::cin >> value) 
    {

        std::cout << escapeChar(value);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: cin ignores whitespace by default, consider using [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), if you want to have cases on character *use* characters, like `'\t'` for tab.

Comment: Also, `case 48-57` is the same as `case -9`, you can't have ranges. And use the [standard character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) instead of making your own.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Demonstrated particularly well in this case by the fact that he's swapped CR and LF.

Comment: I think you can try getche() function to read a single character

Comment: you need to use function `getch()` to do that. It's not possible with cin.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a number of problems. The one you've noted is that the character extraction operator `>>` normally skips white space. You can fix this any of a number of different ways. One would be to add `std::cin >> std::noskipws;` before you loop:

```
std::cout << "Time to read in some characters or whatever...\n";
char value;

std::cin >> std::noskipws; // Added

while (std::cin >> value) 
{
    std::cout << escapeChar(value);
}
```

Another would be to use `get` instead:

```
while (std::cin.get(value))
    std::cout << escapeChar(value);
```

As to the other problems, they include the fact that you've swapped CR and LF in your switch statement, the fact that case statements don't support ranges, and the fact that you repeat `return return_string;` in *every* case of your switch statement.

Personally, I think I'd do the job somewhat differently. I'd probably build a [unordered_]map of strings for the inputs you want to change, then (most likely) use `std::transform` to handle reading and writing the data, and invoking the function to change the individual inputs.

```
class xform { 
    std::map<char, std::string> changes;
public:
    xform() {
        changes['\n'] = "LF";
        changes['\r'] = "CR";
        changes['\t'] = "TAB";
        changes[' '] = "SPACE";
        changes['\\'] = "\\\\";

        for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
            changes[i + '0'] = "\\" + std::to_string(i);

        // ...
    }

    std::string operator()(char in) { 
        auto pos = changes.find(in);

        if (pos != changes.end())
            return pos->second;
        return std::string(1, in);
    }
};

// ...
std::cin >> noskipws;

std::transform(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
               std::istream_iterator<char>(),
               std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
               xform());
```

Another possibility (especially handy if you're doing this enough for speed to matter) would be to use an array of output strings, and fill in the correct value for *every* possible input value. Then you wouldn't need any conditionals when you to the transformation--you'd just write out `table[input]`. Realistically, if you're reading/writing files, it's going to be pretty difficult to get the file I/O fast enough for this to make much (if any) real difference though.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 48-57:
```

The term evaluate to -9, since it's a subtraction operator.
unfortunatly, you can't specify ranges in a switch case, you can add an `if-else` statement after the switch for final validation. (you will have to remove the `default` keyword for that).

Also, the delimiter `cin` uses is whitespace, meaning you will get the words *without* whitespaces anyway.